# Omnistudio flexcards - why does the source code needs to keep two identical lwc components

Tags: omnistudio

when I try to pull source of OmniStudio down to our local repository, I noticed for one Omnistudio flex card, there are usually three parts of source code: 1, the xml under omniUiCard folder 2, the first lwc of the flexcard name which contains all the source code
3, a duplicate version of the lwc component which is kind of a duplicate of the 2nd part.

I am wondering why does the source code needs to keep two identical versions in this case? Even considering version control perspective, in the main file, it can be a much simpler xml/json config file other than recording the whole thing again?